# how to differentiate columns based on if else in sql

Tags: mysql

i have a `order` table with columns `scheduled_arrival_date` and `actual_arrival_date` , i need to  find out which order delivered early and late and i need to differentiate orders based on that(two columns should be created ) , as i don't have permission to create new table so i need get this from query.
i tried this, but am getting in single column

```
SELECT order.id,order.item,
     CASE  WHEN  scheduled_arrival_date >= actual_arrival_date  
                     THEN 'late' 
           WHEN  scheduled_arrival_date <= actual_arrival_date  
                     THEN 'Early'       
     END as delivered   
FROM order
```

Comment: What result you want? Please read [**How-to-Ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
 
 And here is a great place to [**START**](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) to learn how improve your question quality and get better answers.

Comment: i need to create pie chart based on that

Comment: again what result you expect to pass your pie chart?

Comment: orders which delivered  late and early

Comment: we know you need something with late/early. But edit your question and show us how you want your data.

Comment: i need two columns delivered_early and delivered_late and i need to differentiate order.id based on  delivered_early and delivered_late

Comment: Show us db schema, sample data, current and expected output.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT order.id, order.item, 'late' AS late FROM order WHERE scheduled_arrival_date > actual_arrival_date
UNION ALL
SELECT order.id, order.item, 'early' AS early FROM order WHERE scheduled_arrival_date <= actual_arrival_date
```

This query is definely not optimized, but it will work. The first query gather all late shippings and put 'late' into the `late` column. The second one do the exact same trick but with early, and we union all of the result together.

However, i don't really understand why you want two columns, it looks weird this way, your initial request was much better IMO.

**PS: Note that you should not use <= and >= in both of your condition, there is a conflit for the equal case**

Answer (score 0):

As you want to create a pie diagram it seems to me that you are only interested in the numbers (counts) of the two cases. You can do that like this:

```
SELECT COUNT(CASE WHEN actual_arrival_date-scheduled_arrival_date>0 THEN 1 END) late,
       COUNT(CASE WHEN actual_arrival_date-scheduled_arrival_date<=0 THEN 1 END) early 
FROM order
```